# GPIO pins 17 and 18 stuck at logic high after reboot

Tags: gpio

I was experimenting with the GPIO ports when I think I might have shorted pin 18, though I'm not sure how. Now, GPIO pin 17 and 18 are stuck at logic high.

The two pins remain at logic high despite multiple reboots. I've tried changing the logic level on those two pins using Python RPi library, and WiringPi with no effect. If I power off the Raspberry Pi but keep the power supply on, the logic levels on both pins also remain high. The same thing happens when I boot up the Raspberry Pi without the SD card inside.

I've tested other pins and they seem to be alright. Raspbian boots up fine with working USB ports, HDMI display, sound and Ethernet.

Does this mean I've permanently damaged the two GPIO pins?

Comment: Do you mean GPIO 17 and 18 or the physical pins 17 and 18.  They are not the same.

Comment: Yes, you did. Looks like you are lucky, in that you didn't break the entire Pi. Just use the other pins. @graig physical pin 17 is the 3.3V line, so that one should always be (semi-)high.

Comment: @Craig GPIO 17 and GPIO 18. In other word physical pins P1-11 and P1-12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the two pins have been shorted. The impedance level at both pins are significantly lower than the others. I've tested the same pins with a working Raspberry Pi and confirmed it.

Comment: Glad to here you resolved your issue! If you could mark your answer as the answer, which you can do (mark your own answer as answer) that would be great! Thanks!